# Initializing array on the fly in constructor (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, initialization

```
 public class A{
      public A(int[] a){}
 }

 public class B extends A{
      public B(double[] b){
           super({b.length});  //ERROR
      }
 }
```

I want to be able to compile the code above.  To clarify, I have class A and B that extends it.  Class A does not have an empty parameter constructor.  If I don't put a call to super in Class B's constructor on the first line, it will try to call super(), which doesn't exist.  But, I want to call super(int[] a) instead.  I want to do this by taking the length of a given double array and sending it as an array with length 1.  It does not let me do this because apparently you can't declare an array like that, and if I were to declare it on a separate line it would call super() first and that won't work.

Is there any way to declare an int[] on the fly like that?  Or are the only solution here to either make a constructor for A with no parameters or make my own function that returns an int[]?

(Don't ask why I want to send it as an array like that.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you insist on not asking why...

You could make the array, assign the first and only element and send it.

```
public class B extends A{
      public B(double[] b){
           int[] arr = new int[1];
           arr[0] = b.length;
           super(arr);  // broken, super must be first.
      }
}
```

This means you must have a one line solution. Luckily, Java provides an in-line way to make a series of elements into an array at compile time.

```
public class B extends A{
      public B(double[] b){
           super(new int[]{b.length});  // FIXED
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know you can declare and initialize arrays like that at the same time.  That is just what I was looking for.

Comment: HOWEVER, your first solution would still not work because you're missing a call to super() in the first line of the constructor, so it would be called automatically.  But since I lack a constructor A(), this would cause an error.  Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: The first example won't compile. You need to call super/this constructor at the very first line. Second exp +1.

Comment: You can't call `super` like that in your first code. The correct answer is the second one

Answer (score 4):

Yeap, try:

```
 super(new int[]{b.length});  //ERROR NO MORE
```

Comment: No, that would just make the length of the array equal to b.length.  I want the length to be 1, and the value of the first (and only) entry to be b.length.

Answer (score 4):

you can also

```
 public class A{
    public A(int... a){}
 }

 public class B extends A{
    public B(double[] b){
       super( b.length ); 
  }
 }
```